# angularjs filter array of objects based on specific attributes values

Tags: angularjs

In the below code to search the record in the table, i added the "searchTutorial" at the filter option (filter:searchTutorila).

But if wanted to search only by the courseName and FacultyName, how the code has to be changed.

> ```
> > <input id="searchCourseFaculty" type="text" ng-model="searchTutorial">
> > <tr ng-repeat ="train in training | filter:searchTutorial"> <td>{{train.SessionID}}</td><td>{{train.SessionDate}}</td><td>{{train.CourseName}}</td><td>{{train.FacultyName}}</td>
> > </tr>
> ```

If any know the answer, please post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <input id="searchCourseFaculty" type="text" ng-model="query">
```

in controller

```
$scope.searchTutorial = function(train) {
            return (angular.lowercase(train.CourseName).indexOf(angular.lowercase($scope.query) || '') !== -1 ||
            angular.lowercase(train.FacultyName).indexOf(angular.lowercase($scope.query) || '') !== -1);
        };
```

Comment: Just wanted to know, is there any other ways to achieve the same stuff using filters only

Comment: other way means? I have used filters only...  by default angular in-built filter will search on all the attributes, if u want to filter based on few specific attributes, this is the way.
If this solves ur problem, u can mark it as accepted.

Comment: How to do that, i have added pionts